# There was no endpoint listening although there is no firewall running

Tags: c#, wcf

I try to build an application to send messages between 2 machines usinf WCF according this article: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-BYIQQYwjQ

After follow all the steps and when the server and the client runs on the same machine all works fine. 
when moved my Client (simple console application) to another machine i have changed **localhost** from `http://localhost:8733/MySampleWCFService/` to my machine `IP address` (both machines in the same network and there is no Firewall running but received the error 
There was no endpoint listening

This is my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFServiceHostingInWinService.MySampleWCFService">
        <endpoint
          name="ServiceHttpEndPoint"
          address="" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="WCFServiceHostingInWinService.IMySampleWCFService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint
          name="ServiceMexEndPoint"
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/MySampleWCFService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Maybe it could be an permissions issue ?

Comment: Try to change the "localhost:8733" for a "<IP>:8733" and please show me the the other end .config

Comment: Are you sure there's no firewall? Have you explicitly disabled windows firewall on the server? Can you get to the service locally by using the ip instead of localhost?

Comment: Do i need to change the localhost:8733" for a "<IP>:8733 also in the service machine ?

Comment: OK after change localhost:8733" for a "<IP>:8733 it's working now but only if the firewall is disabled, what i need to configure if i want to keep my firewall running ?

Comment: You should host it on `IIS` if you want to keep firewall running.

Comment: What should i change in my project to host it on IIS ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: For your firewall, you need to open a firewall exception on port 8733. On the server it should allow incoming traffic to your service application (is it a self-hosted console app?) and on the client, it should be outgoing from your client.

Comment: Can i have a code example hot to do it ? (allow incoming - outgoing traffic)